# Force Gatsby to prefetch linked page

Tags: state, gatsby, prefetch, link-prefetch

In my app, I'm storing state in a global object (similar to, but not Redux). When users navigate around the site, I want this state to persist. Gatsby intelligently tries to prefetch page content for links it finds on the page, but sometimes when navigating to a particular route, the page is fetched from the server, the window reloads, and I lose my state.

A little more context: I'm already using the Gatsby `Link` component for every link in the app, and if needing to change routes programmatically, I'm using the Gatsby `navigate` function. I've tried storing state in `location.state`, but this is also wiped if the page is not prefetched.

Is there any way to force Gatsby to prefetch routes so I don't lose my app state?

UPDATE:

Adding code snippet from my `gatsby-ssr.js` in case that might be related:

```
// gatsby-ssr.js

import React from "react";
import wrapWithState from "@state/wrapWithState"; <-- this is a React context provider

import { SearchConfig } from "@modules/search/index";
import { DefaultLayout, HeaderWrap, Lang } from "@layout";

export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithState;

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  const { location } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Lang currentPath={location.href} />
      <SearchConfig />
      <HeaderWrap currentPath={location.href} />
      <DefaultLayout {...props}>{element}</DefaultLayout>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really. If a link is not generated using `Link` component it will behave just like a regular anchor and the browser will perform a page load (resetting your state). First identify which links act like regular links and see why `Link` component is not used there.

Comment: Thanks @Z. Zlatev, I am using `Link` everywhere (or the `navigate` func when routing programmatically), and what I'm seeing is that *most* of the time the page is prefetched, but sometimes it isn't. I just added a note about how I'm also using `gatsby-ssr` because seems like that could be involved in Gatsby deciding to fetch from the server.